# File Copy Locks File So Data Cannot Be Written

Tags: c#, webserver, file-copying

I have a couple of file templates stored in C:\Webs\web-n-rsgpsd\Administration\Templates as part of a deployed web application. Data should then be exported to a copy of the file (copied from Templates to ExtractOutput), but each time it runs, the application errors with a 500 - Internal Server Error and according to the application log on the server:
***The process cannot access the file 'C:\Webs\web-n-rsgpsd\Administration\ExtractOutput\AskDataExtractTemplate.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.0***
So whilst the file is copied (and can be seen in the ExtractOutput folder, the data can't be written to it. If I attempt to open the file from the ExtractOutput folder, it says the file is locked for editing by 'another user'.
Here is the code that creates the copy of the template:

```
    private FileInfo GetExportFilename()
    {
        const string templateFilename = "AskDataExtractTemplate.xlsx";
        var templateFileInfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath($"~/Administration/Templates/{templateFilename}"));
        var temporaryFile = Server.MapPath($"~/Administration/ExtractOutput/{templateFilename}");
        templateFileInfo.CopyTo(temporaryFile, true);
        templateFileInfo = new FileInfo(temporaryFile) { IsReadOnly = false };
        return templateFileInfo;
    }
```

This is the connection string it is then used with to export data:
*Connection string:Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Webs\web-n-rsgpsd\Administration\ExtractOutput\ASKDataExtractTemplate.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'*
Can anyone shed any light on why the file is locked, and therefore the data can't be written to it?

Comment: Use process explorer or some other tool to check the file-lock. Also note that it is fairly common for "another process" to be *your* process. So make sure to always dispose file streams and ensure nothing else in your application is using the files.

Comment: Sometimes the kernel can hold the file open for a tiny bit longer, so you may have to wait a second or two to read it again after writing and closing it. You could try manually copying it yourself using two `FileStream`s where the destination is opened under a permissive sharing.

Comment: But the issue is that the writing isn't happening because the file is locked, and even after everything is closed (OldDBCommand, OleDbConnection and Response), the file is still locked. Nothing else uses the file as it's only relevant to this one process. The Output folder is empty (except for a stub text file) on deploy, but as soon as it get's copied, it is locked and remains that way until I deploy again to remove it.

Comment: Are you *sure* you aren't opening it twice?

Comment: As it's being populated with an OleDbConnection, there is no file being opened in the normal sense. I've integrated some logging to understand what is happening and the INSERT INTO is correct, and when it performs the ExecuteNonQuery for each row, it appears to work, but the file is actually empty.